# Google Script, how to use negative offset?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function calcPortfolioValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  var col = sheet.getCurrentCell().getColumn();
  var activeCell = sheet.getRange( row, col );
  var prevCellVal = sheet.getRange( row - 1, col ).getValue();
  return prevCellVal; // end prematurely to narrow where error is
}
```

I am trying to access the cell above activeCell. However, I get an error in the line when defining prevCell. Is there a way to reference a previous row or col in google scripts for google sheets?

The error I recieve is
"The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line x, file "x")"
Where line x points to the line where I define prevCell.

Comment: I think that in your script, when there is the active cell on the row 1, such error occurs at ``sheet.getRange( row - 1, col )``, because ``row - 1`` becomes 0. In order to avoid this issue, for example, please run it when the row of active cell is more than 2 using ``if``.

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: You were helpful! I used your advice and encapsulated my row-1 in an if statement to get rid of the coordinates range error

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I thought that in your situation, ``offset()`` might be also useful. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset

Answer (score 1):

Ah okay. I believe I figured it out. It was a case of bad google scripts design.

1. When I would "Run" my code in the script.google.com site, I would receive a red error on the top stating "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line #, file name)
2. My code would run fine despite the error from 1.
3. When adding to my code, I have to refresh my google sheets everytime to update the script.